# Convert response body of a Quarkus Test

Tags: testing, junit, quarkus, rest-assured

I'm trying to test my Quarkus application. I want to check that a response is greater than 0, the problem is that the endpoint I'm calling return a String and not a number. How can I convert the response to a number and check that it is greater than 0?

```
   @Test
   void getAdminListSize() {
       given()
               .when()
               .header("Authorization", token_admin)
               .get(PATH + "/get?listSize=true")
               .then()
               .statusCode(200)
               .body(greaterThan(0))
       ;
   }
```

This is the response I receive: "28357".
This is the error I get:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
Response body doesn't match expectation.
Expected: a value greater than <0>
Actual: 28357
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just extract the body to a variable and work with it

```
@Test
   void getAdminListSize() {
       String s = given()
               .when()
               .header("Authorization", token_admin)
               .get(PATH + "/get?listSize=true")
               .then()
               .assertThat()
               .statusCode(200)
               .extract()
               .body()
               .asString();

       
              convert s into a integer and do the assert
   }
```

Other option is use `.as(Clazz.class)` and work with your dto if you have one